# Private comments

Tags: feature-request

What about the idea of being able to mark comments "private", visible only to the person @mentioned (and the sender)?

First and least importantly, this would accommodate people who feel compelled to make "THANKS!!" comments. In addition, in many cases I myself point out typos or other minor problems in comments, but I expect the poster to make the fix and don't really want or need this comment to be visible to everyone, and often delete it later anyway. Then there are the cases where a comment is essentially a rant addressed personally to the poster.

The proposed interface is to add a new button under the current "Add Comment" button, labeled "Add private comment". Private comments would be made visually distinct somehow. The addressee would be allowed to flag the comment even if they did not have enough rep to do so normally.

I think this would result in cleaner comment threads, and also reduce the need to flag and moderator work cleaning up flagged comments.

This feature request is semi-related to [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user), which got 415 upvotes. Although that post is about personal messages rather than private comments, it is worth mentioning some arguments against the idea given in the accepted answer:

> It could hide information from the community: useful information transmitted privately is unavailable to other readers, subverting the core purpose of the site.

Right, hiding is the point. It's a mystery how hiding private interactions would "subvert the core purpose of the site".

> It could be used to harass other users ("Answer my question!", "Accept my answer!", "Yer momma so fat she overflows the stack!", etc...)

Such harassment already occurs in comments; allowing comments to be made private would assuage this problem, not aggravate it.

Comment: "allowing comments to be made private would assuage this problem, not aggravate it." Only one way to find out for sure...

Comment: How about at 10k rep or something. I could see the use of this to some extent. But the non-transparency of it all. Plus the normal "How many people does this benefit" slam that ingenious ideas often get. It's frustrating, but to keep the site from turning into the Wild West, we do need to be treated like schoolchildren.

Answer (score 10):

There's one big problem with this that I see right away, and it's probably enough on its own to prevent this from being implemented.

The one type of comment that would really flourish – or should I say *fester* – is abusive comments. This is the real danger: What happens if it's a user with no rep to flag? What if the user is scared, and the offense goes unreported or even escalates?

Community involvement helps to get rid of abusive comments, possibly before the intended target sees it.

---

Beyond that, I imagine it would just be an annoyance.

Imagine getting dozens of similar, nearly identical messages all giving the same criticism. There's no way to know what's already been said.

---

You should just flag "thanks" comments as too chatty as you see them. They probably won't be gone as fast as you want, but it's the easiest way.

Comment: Well, easiest for everyone but the moderator who has to deal with it.

Comment: *What happens if it's a user with no rep to flag?* Good point, I've added a note about that to the proposal.

Comment: It's much easier for us to deal with when you have more eyes flagging them for our attention. I can't imagine just how much abuse would fly under the radar if it wasn't for the community, especially considering that we already have people who have the guts to abuse others *in public*.

Comment: And, if you haven't seen the anonymous mod messages feature request yet, [check out the kind of stuff we already get in our private mod message inboxes on a daily basis](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283725/make-moderator-messages-anonymous#comment919684_283725).

Answer (score 4):

The downsides appear to outweigh the couple of benefits this would have.

- Technical comments, about typos and such, *need* to be public in case they're not implemented right away. Users would likely often choose the wrong (private) route if the system offered it to them.
- The main use case for private comments would likely be coding requests and requests for one-on-one help. They're impossible to filter, and each would show up in the notification bar, tiring users with unwanted communication. That's where the "would subvert the core purpose of the site" bit comes in.
- Insults and such can currently be cleaned up by *anybody*. That's why it happens so fast and there is almost zero litter on the site. In a private comments system, cleanup would be much slower because it'd depend entirely on moderators. And if you're not there to flag (or don't understand the system) the comments never go away.
- "Thanks" comments or coding requests become annoying very fast if you're a power user of the site. You'd likely have to create a possibility for users to opt out of private comments, and an option to block users from comment-messaging you - making the system complicated and even less attractive.